# map_fn with dynamic shape tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have a question about tensorflow.

Suppose I have a black-white image and I want to do some thing with black pixels only. So I am using tf.where to get the location of those pixels and pass those locations to tf.map_fn, like:

```
def to_do_something(pixel):
    to_do_some_fancy_thing
    return

indices = tf.where(black_white_image)
tf.map_fn(to_do_something, indices)
```

But now the problem I am facing is that the length of indices is unknown but map_fn() expects an known shape. If I passed indices to map_fn, I will receive error message like:

> File "/opt/anaconda2-4.3.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 371, in make_tensor_proto
>       raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
>   ValueError: None values not supported.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Thanks,
XP

Comment: Actually, I used this function in a loss function in Keras, so I don't know the length of indices until I feed the training data into it. Not sure what you mean replace them with Zero? Here "None" refers the 0-dimension of tensor.

Also, for an unknown image, we don't know how many pixels are black and white, the length of indices is always a variable.

Comment: I use tensorflow 1.9.0, and it works fine, maybe it has been fixed from some version of tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

For an image of shape `(batch_size, n, m)` with `k` black pixels, you could use a `(batch_size, n*m, 2)` array where the first `k` values in axis 1 (i.e. `out[:, :k]`) correspond to the 2D coordinates of the pixels, along with the integer `k` corresponding to the number of non-black pixels.

Alternatively, you can do the `tf.where` inside `to_do_something`.

I fear neither is going to be particularly fast..

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But k is unknown in advance, how can I get this number?

Comment: `tf.reduce_sum(input, axis=(1, 2))` (`axis=(1, 2, 3)`) if the shape is `(batch_size, n, m, 1)1)